# Magento Layer Navigation Move after Custom Block

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, blocks

I want to move layer navigation after My custom Block i tried lot of things but its not working even its still showing there after removing layer navigation code form "Catalog Category (Anchor)" in catalog.xml

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="left_nav" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml"/>
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: which magento version,you have using and which  package>

Comment: I create my own package "yas > iel" actually its copy of base..

Answer (score 1):

Change the after alias name  `left_nav`:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="left_nav" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml"/>
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="left_nav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: Thanks but this code is not working.. i don`t know form where package is getting this block, its still there even if i am removing this code form catalog.xml

<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="left_nav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>